# How to check, if bitmask contains a bit?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the following bit mask's

```
class FLAG(IntEnum):
   DEFAULT = 0b0
```

and a class that deals with them:

```
class Converter:
  def has_flag(self, val):
    return self._descriptor & val == val
```

I found that `has_flag` method contains a bug because every other flag contains a `DEFAULT` flag. What is the best way to fix that?
`flag`s are mutually exclusive.

I found the following solution:

```
def has_flag(self, val):
    if val == FLAG.DEFAULT:
        return self._descriptor == val
    return self._descriptor & val == val
```

Is there any other way to fix that bug?

Comment: Just decide what should happen if `val` is zero. You could raise an exception, too. The title of this question doesn't seem to correspond to what you are asking, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DEFAULT_ZERO isn’t really a flag (it is the absence of flags) it should need to be treated differently; your proposed way is perfectly reasonable.

Note that you can’t set the DEFAULT_ZERO flag either, again because it isn’t a flag.